# Создание возможных вариантов списка способом рекурсии в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу решить задание. Необходимо вывести все возможные комбинации списка рекурсией. Если вырезаю часть кода из функции `def get_combinations()`, все работает, но в коде ниже нет.

```
class CombinationsList:
    @staticmethod
    def get_combinations(my_list):
        """
        :param self:
        :param my_list: list
        :return: list[list]
        """
        # YOUR CODE HERE
        if len(my_list) == 0:
            return [[]]
        cs = []
        for c in get_combinations(my_list[1:]):
            cs += [c, c+[my_list[0]]]
        return cs

print('Combinations:', CombinationsList().get_combinations([1, 2, 'a']))
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло. 
Но осталась еще одна проблема: Получаемый результат: Combinations: [[], [1], [2], [2, 1], ['a'], ['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['a', 2, 1]]. 
А мне нужно: Combinations:[[], [1], [2], ['a'], [1, 2], [1, 'a'], [2, 'a'], [1, 2, 'a']]
Не могу понять почему оно в первой итерации не берет третий элемент исходного списка [1, 2, ‘a’]

Answer (score 1):

Когда зовёте статический метод класса указывайте его полное название.

```
for c in CombinationsList.get_combinations(my_list[1:]):
```

Или используйте `@classmethod` вместо `@staticmethod`, тогда имя класса автоматически будет передано в качестве первого аргумента.

```
    @classmethod
    def get_combinations(cls, my_list):
        ...
        for c in cls.get_combinations(my_list[1:]):
```

И в обоих случаях создавать экземпляр класса не обязательно. Можно вызывать без `()` - `CombinationsList.get_combinations([1, 2, 'a'])`.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло. 
Но осталась еще одна проблема: Получаемый результат: Combinations: [[], [1], [2], [2, 1], ['a'], ['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['a', 2, 1]]. 
А мне нужно: Combinations:[[], [1], [2], ['a'], [1, 2], [1, 'a'], [2, 'a'], [1, 2, 'a']]
Не могу понять почему оно в первой итерации не берет третий элемент исходного списка [1, 2, ‘a’]

Comment: @RomanParkhomenko Так там же есть элемент `['a']`. Только он в списке позже.

Comment: есть но не в том порядке. Итерации проходят в таком порядке по значениям списка: [0, 1, [0, 1] и только потом переходит к значению 2. А мне нужно чтобы в первую очередь прошло [0, 1, 2 и только потом [0, 1]. Ошибка гдето в цикле которые регламентируют порядок итераций, но не могу понять где именно ошибка